# Is a phonorecord a sound recording on a specific material object, such as an audio book on a CD?

Tags: copyright

Based on definitions according to [17 U.S.C. § 101](https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title17-section101&num=0&edition=prelim) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20201107155724/https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid%3AUSC-prelim-title17-section101&num=0&edition=prelim)):

> "Phonorecords" are material objects in which sounds, other than those
> accompanying a motion picture or other audiovisual work, are fixed by
> any method now known or later developed, and from which the sounds can
> be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly
> or with the aid of a machine or device. The term "phonorecords"
> includes the material object in which the sounds are first fixed.

> "Sound recordings" are works that result from the fixation of a series
> of musical, spoken, or other sounds, but not including the sounds
> accompanying a motion picture or other audiovisual work, regardless of
> the nature of the material objects, such as disks, tapes, or other
> phonorecords, in which they are embodied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It’s a sound recording that has a physical existence

That might be a CD, a hard drive (whether on a local computer or a server in the cloud), a cassette, a vinyl record, or anything else that does, did or may in the future be possible.

Comment: besides the mentioned, Shellac, wax cylinders, audio on a magnetic tape roll and for the love of god: **punchcards** are known to be used to record audio.